# Python ,Is this syntax correct

Tags: python, command, arguments, line

```
#filename= sys.argv[1]

#topic= sys.argv[2]

# a function --> aggregator(filename,topic).Can you then call the function in main() as follows

aggregator(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2])
```

When you type at the pycharm terminal prompt..python aggregator.py something.txt 
it generates an error

```
File "aggregator.py", line 68, in main
    aggregator(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Could someone tell me why? Thanks in advance

Comment: Which part of "list index out of range" are you having trouble with?

Comment: you have supplied a single arg not two - `python aggregator.py something.txt` and so `sys.argv[2]` returns an list index out of range error

Comment: The error indicates that `sys.argv` has length 2 or less, yet you are trying to index the third element of it (index 2).  Try checking `len(sys.argv)` to see if the arguments are present before attempting to access them.

Comment: You're only passing in `something.txt`, meaning the `argv` is only two values (`aggregator.py`, `something.txt`).

Comment: Try `print(sys.argv)`. `sys.argv[0]` is the first item, `sys.argv[1]` is the second and and `sys.argv[2]` is... well there isn't anything there.

Comment: def main():
    """
    Generate error messages
    """
    import sys

    # Get the command line arguments
    #filename= sys.argv[1]
    #topic= sys.argv[2]
    aggregator(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2])

     # check for the right number of arguments
    #if arguments <3 or >3 generate error messages
    if len(sys.argv)!= 3:
       print('Error: Invalid number of arguments \nUsage: aggregate.py filename topic' )    ......It should print this error message if arguments less than 3